# Changing userpath with python

Tags: windows, python-2.7, path

i wanted to change the environment variable using python, but i need to load into the Windows Command Shell a variable which is stored in python.

I tried it like this :

```
userpath = 'C:/test_folder'
cmd = 'Path=%Path%; %s' % (userpath)
os.system(cmd)
```

But im am getting this error here :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\Python_Script\path_cahnge.py", line 7, in 
    cmd = 'Path=%Path%; %s' % (userpath)
ValueError: unsupported format character 'P' (0x50) at index 6

can someone help me with that ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to modify `PATH` in a child cmd process? That doesn't persist. Anyway, what you want is `userpath = r'C:\test_folder';` `cmd = 'path %%PATH%%;%s' % userpath;` `os.system(cmd)`.  I made the following changes. `userpath` needs to use a backlash, so make it a raw string. cmd's `path` command doesn't require `=` assignment; just pass the new path as a parameter. The `%` characters need to be escaped as `%%`. And the elements of `PATH` are delimited by semicolons without spaces.

Comment: i need to modify the path for a child session because i need different compiles for every session i start, so it can be selected by the user.
and it is a good feature if the path returns to default after the cmd session

Comment: Depending on what you're doing you might instead want something like the following: `environ = os.environ.copy();` `environ['PATH'] += '%s%s' % (os.pathsep, userpath)`; `subprocess.call(command, env=environ)`. Add `shell=True` to the latter if running in the shell is required.